# Removing SQLLite data entry from Context Menu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

Basically I have a bookmarks database, and for a long click I have a context menu option, one of these options is to remove an entry.  What is the best way to get the Row ID for each item?

I am using Cursors to access to fill the data, but the Listview assigns it's own IDs that is not in relation with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the row id? If you have enough information from the row to find the row id, you can simply delete the data directly with a where clause

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN + "=" + value, null);
```

In order to be more specific we really need more information on what you are doing. Please post some code showing what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I didn't think of this....

So it would be acceptable practice to just search the database by the bookmark name and remove it that way?

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe the way you delete based on id is similar, except you are searching based on that id. You will have to use whatever it is you are storing in the list to perform the delete

Comment: Do you know anyway I can store the RowID in the row on creation and then retrieve using AdapterMenuInfo?

Comment: Actually, if you are using a CursorAdapter you can call `getItemId(int position)` to get the id, assuming you call your id column `_id`.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the position function instead of the the GetID function.!